# All slide master placeholders default to type 14

Tags: python, vba, powerpoint, win32com

I am playing around with using win32com to create power points programmatically. I have a issue when snooping around in the slide master.

Open a power point, go to

Home -> Editing -> Select -> Selection Pane

Then do

View -> Slide Master

I deleted all the contents of layout 1 and inserted a picture placeholder as shown below

[image]

```
import win32com.client
pp = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
pres = pp.Presentations.Open("<your pptx file name>.pptx")
design = pres.Designs
design = pres.Designs(1)
master = design.SlideMaster
layouts = master.CustomLayouts
>>> layouts(1).shapes(1).Type
14 
>>> layouts(1).shapes(1).Name
'Picture Placeholder 7
```

My issue is that the Type enumeration, which I reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppplaceholdertype), 14 is for ppPlaceholderHeader. Why is it not ppPlaceholderPicture? I.e. a Type of 18.

Perhaps I am navigating incorrectly and looking at wrong objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALL placeholders are Type 14 objects.  If you want to know the type of placeholder, use:

```
.PlaceholderFormat.Type
```

Comment: Ah! My man. Thank you very much. I'm still learning the object models.

Comment: And for the sake of completeness, .PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType will give you the type of any content the placeholder contains (ie, it'll return 3 for a content placeholder that has a Chart)